# How to set orientable a GTK_WINDOW

Tags: c, gtk

I have developed a C application with `GTK` embedded on arm architecture with screen having horizontal orientation.
Now I have change the screen and it is mapped with vertical orientation and I want use the same application.
There is a simple way to change orientation of my main `GTK_WINDOW` with all its widgets?

It exits `gtk_orientable_set_orientation()` but a `GTK_WINDOW` cannot be cast as `GTK_ORIENTABLE`.

Answer (score 1):

The orientation is for widgets that may have different orientations for different instances. Changing the orientation of a GTK_WINDOW makes little sense for me. It would mean you'd have some windows with default orientation, and your application with another orientation ?

If you're on embedded, chances are that you're fullscreen, and then that's your display server that handles screen rotation. Try to use xrandr on your PC to change the orientation. All applications will update themselves to respect the new orientation.

Comment: Thank you! it is the good way! I have change xorg.conf commenting line #Option "Rotate" "CCW" and that solves it!

Answer (score 0):

a `GtkWindow` is a `GtkBin`, i.e. a container that can only have one child. the `GtkOrientable` interface is meant for containers and layout managers that have more than one child, and *can* be oriented (for instance, orienting a `GtkGrid` would be pointless). orientation also changes the size request in case the widgets have different width-for-height and height-for-width preferred size.

you also have to realize that just changing the orientation of a layout manager does not automatically make landscape/portrait orientation happen, unless your display is perfectly square; the different size constraint of the two orientations require a different layout, which mean a different organization of the widget hierarchy.